# why realm.io is needs in additional frameworks?

Tags: realm

I create app with Realm database (RealmSwift)
When i try build app, there are a lot of errors , experimentally i found several libraries i should link to project for success compilation.
But i don't want to get it for final app version (size of app will very big), what to do ?
These frameworks for example:

```
CoreVideo.framework
CoreMedia.framework
AudioToolbox.framework
CommLibiOS.a
MediaLibiOS.a
```

My app doesn't use any video/audo/media features of Realm , i don't know why i need to link it.

If I try to delete for example AudioToolbox.framework from linked list , i have a lot of errors like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AudioComponentFindNext", referenced from:
      -[MPAudioUnitEngine voiceAudioUnit] in MediaLibiOS.a(MPAudioUnitEngine.o)
```

Why Realm needs these libraries? 
p.s. sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Realm doesn't require linking any of the libraries you've referenced. These must be referenced in your own Xcode project's configuration.

Realm Swift requires the following libraries to be linked: Realm, Foundation & libc++. Following the installation instructions in Realm's documentation should get all this set up properly: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation

I suggest you look at some of the Realm example Xcode projects to compare and identify what you may be doing differently. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples